# Windows Forms C# - Dynamic mask textbox money Input

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, mask, currency

Windows Forms C# - I would like to make a textbox that automatically changes each time a user types or deletes one key from the textbox. I developed part of code.

```
    //This will convert value from textbox to currency format when focus leave textbox
    private void txtValormetrocubico_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal cubic = Convert.ToDecimal(txtValormetrocubico.Text);
        txtValormetrocubico.Text = string.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToDecimal(cubic));
        MessageBox.Show(txtValormetrocubico.Text);
    }


    //this only allow numbers and "." and "," on textimbox imput
    private void txtValormetrocubico_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
    && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
    && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != ',')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if (e.KeyChar == '.'
            && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

            if (e.KeyChar == ','
                && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(',') > -1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }          
    }
```

The first time I enter a value in the text box, the value is converted to currency format perfectly, like `300` to `$ 300.00`. But I edit this textbox value again and press enter, it gives an error: "Input String was not in a Correct Format" pointing to the line below:

```
decimal cubic = Convert.ToDecimal(txtValormetrocubico.Text);
```

I think the problem is caused by the fact that the value is already in decimal format. So when I click on the field and press enter again, it causes an error because the value cannot be parsed.  How do I avoid this error ?

**EDIT:**
My previous question was my first. As I am new user and don't have much knowledge in C#, I forgot to post my code.  After studying some more, I made part of it work. Only this little problem remains. Please vote up, I was banned and cant make new questions because I had 7 down votes.

Thanks guys.

Comment: dont understood why it was closed, i think my question is too clear.

Comment: Oh, it's very clear.  You weren't asking for help.  You were asking for someone to do the code for you.  This isn't a site to do that.  Next time, try asking a *question* about the problem you are having and show the code that you were using.  You didn't post anything like that.  Also, you didn't specify the platform: web, winforms, wpf, etc.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, i was banned because i had 7 votes -, not can make new questions now. As i am new user on stackoverflow and have little knowlodge on C#, on previous question i dont put any code, so i study more and was able to make code work,, but with only 1 error in runtime. Please vote up to unban my user.. Thanks for all guys

Comment: +1 for doing some additional studying AND coming back to improve your question :) Do not forget to specify your platform like LarsTech mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for that, already had 2 vote up, remains 5. in title i said C#. Thanks again guys

Comment: There is a separate category for "vote to reopen". The question will be re-opened if it gets one more vote in that category. BTW, "platform" was referring to LarsTech's comment: * Also, you didn't specify the platform: web, winforms, wpf, etc.*

Comment: Now understood, edited, its windows form. Sory for noob, it my firsts posts. Thanks for that

Comment: Please vote up, now all is ok and i have -4 votes

Comment: @felipeSalomao have you any more questions? Did i answer your question or did i misunderstand it? Leave a comment and i will try to help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the string contains the currency symbol

```
private void TextBox_LeaveEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    if(tb.Text.Length>0){
        decimal cubic = Convert.ToDecimal(tb.Text);
        tb.Text = string.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToDecimal(cubic));
        label1.Text = tb.Text;
    }
}
```

Above the textbox.Text is set to contain the currency information:

```
tb.Text = string.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToDecimal(cubic));
```

Since the textbox now contains a currency symbol (like € or $) the `Convert.ToDecimal` fails as soon as the TextBox_LeaveEvent fires again:

```
decimal cubic = Convert.ToDecimal(tb.Text);
```

If you [bing for c# masked textbox](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-EN&q=c#%20masked%20textbox%20example) you can find [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1534/Masked-C-TextBox-Control) about masked textboxes. You cold also test if the string contains any non-number-charakters (`if(tbText.IndexOf(" ") >-1){...}`)

### Update with basic example

I uploaded a [very basic example to remove the currency formating](https://github.com/surfmuggle/StackoverflowWinformQuestions/blob/master/TextBoxMaskInput/TextBoxMaskedInput.cs) to github:

```
string RemoveCurrencyFormating(string input)
{    
    if(input.IndexOf(" ") !=-1){
       var money = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(" ")-1);            
       return String.Format("{0:D0}", money);               
    }
    return ""; // Todo: add Error Handling
}
```

On TextBox Enter Event you can do the following:

```
void TextBox_EnterEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    tb.Text = RemoveCurrencyFormating(tb.Text);
}
```